# Merge [ndk] into [android-ndk] and blacklist the former one

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-block-request

There are two tags now [android-ndk](/questions/tagged/android-ndk) and [ndk](/questions/tagged/ndk) for the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html).
Considering tags usage (1075 for *android-ndk* and 322 for *ndk*), and since it is [explicitly encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info) to:

> use the Android-specific tags such as [android-intent], not [intent]

I suggest to replace all [ndk](/questions/tagged/ndk) with [android-ndk](/questions/tagged/android-ndk) and make the synonym: [ndk](/questions/tagged/ndk) -> [android-ndk](/questions/tagged/android-ndk).

**Update**

I've changed my mind about the synonym creation. I think [ndk](/questions/tagged/ndk) tag is too generic and should be blacklisted (after merging with [android-ndk](/questions/tagged/android-ndk) of course). See my answer below for the details.

Comment: What's the state of this request? I see some discussion in answers and comments, but I don't see a particular consensus. Can you summarize what's going on and propose what should be done (do you still want a synonym to be created, for example) in an answer or an edit to the question? Thanks.

Comment: @AnnaLear I've changed my mind about the synonym creation. I think `ndk` tag is too generic and should be blacklisted instead. Please, see my answer for the details.

Comment: Ah, moderators don't have the ability to blacklist tags (that's a dev-only thing).

Comment: @AnnaLear I see. Can you please replace `ndk` with `android-ndk` for the existing questions? Concerning blacklisting. I've added `tag-blacklist-request` tag to this question. Should I do something else to draw developers attention to my request?

Comment: See my answer for an update. I'm marking this status-completed, though the tag isn't going to be blacklisted at this point. If it consistently comes back again, we can review if it really needs to be on the blacklist.

Comment: I don't agree with the idea of blacklisting the `[ndk]` tag, because it's *not* a meta tag. It adds *some* information to the post. Questions are often tagged just `[sql]` (which by itself is not very useful), but it's still not blacklisted.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can infer which ndk the OP is talking about from the post, so burnination is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I merged [ndk](/questions/tagged/ndk) into [android-ndk](/questions/tagged/android-ndk) without creating a synonym.

Having spoken to Rebecca Chernoff... since the tag is now gone, there might not be any need to blacklist it. It will age away on its own without any questions and if it comes back, we can review it again.

Comment: It has come back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ndk. At the moment there are 96 questions tagged with the [tag:ndk] tag, and all of them are actually about the Android NDK.

Comment: @Idolon I merged them again, this time with a synonym to remap future tags.

Answer (score 3):

There are other NDKs out there - there's one out there for the Playbook. There aren't any questions with the [playbook] tag yet, but assuming [ndk] to mean Android could create confusion later.

Comment: Yes, there are. Currently [ndk] is mistakenly used instead of [android-ndk] thus I thought it would be a good idea to synonymize it. The other option would be to explicitly write in the [ndk] tag excerpt something like: `This tag should be used for generic questions about native development kits, for questions about Android NDK use [android-ndk] instead.`

Comment: @Idolon I would suspect there wouldn't be any substantial questions about NDKs in general.  It might be better to eliminate the tag, and blacklist it if it gets created again and causes problems.

Comment: Oh, moderators can blacklist tag creation? :-) Didn't know about that. Nice feature... Then it really could be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

The search `[ndk] -[android] -[android-ndk] -android` returns no results, <s>so I'd say this is a good solution</s> (but that search doesn't work, see comments).

[ndk](/questions/tagged/ndk) should probably be merged but not synonymized, since there are other NDKs out there including the iPhone one seemingly referred to in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427748/how-do-i-turn-on-rtti-with-cygwin).

Comment: I find 29 questions, with [\[ndk\] -\[android\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ndk+-android).

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes, those 29 are either tagged `[android-ndk]` or mention "android" somewhere.  **Edit:** Or not.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427748/how-do-i-turn-on-rtti-with-cygwin) and its answer don't mention "android" but it still doesn't show up in my search.  Bizarre.

Comment: The first question I see in that search page doesn't mention Android, nor is tagged [tag:android-ndk]. I am not sure the tag is correctly used, in that case, though.

Comment: I've asked about this search result [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113542/is-search-broken-or-do-i-just-not-understand-it).

Comment: @kiamlaluno I'll look through those 29 questions now and retag appropriately.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Done - retagged all except this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7793588/648313 asked by 1rep user. It's really difficult to tell what NDK is meant there. I flagged it for moderator attention (to improve or delete), you can support this flag if you'd like ;-)

Comment: @MatthewRead [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7427748/648313) you mentioned is actually about Android NDK and cocos2d-x (C++ port of cocos2d game engine). I retagged it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

As @GrantPalin already noticed there are other NDKs out there. A [quick search](http://google.com/search?q=ndk%20native%20-android) in Google proves that:

- BlackBerry Playbook NDK
- Windows NT NDK
- ReactOS NDK
- Amiga NDK
- …

Thus, I think it would be better to replace [ndk](/questions/tagged/ndk) with [android-ndk](/questions/tagged/android-ndk) on existing questions (I've just rechecked there is no question which is tagged with the former and not tagged with the latter one). And instead of creating the synonym we'd better eliminate and blacklist the [ndk](/questions/tagged/ndk) tag as I believe it's too general to be used on its own.