# Update the search tips page to describe the use of the minus operator

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

### Edit:

#### **Could we get the `-[tag]` and `-word` usage documented** on [the search tips page](https://stackoverflow.com/search)?

<s>As Tim notes in the comments, it appears the "-" operator doesn't work for words, just tags.  (Is there a reason for this?  Is it too expensive an operation?)</s> (See Nick's answer.)

<s>I also propose that we **give some sort of warning when `-word` is used in a search**, like:</s>

> The minus operator can only be used with tags.  Did you mean to type `-[word]`?

Below is the original version of this post.

---

At the time I posted this, [the search `[ndk] -[android] -[android-ndk] -android`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bndk%5D+-%5Bandroid%5D+-%5Bandroid-ndk%5D+-android) returned no results, despite the fact that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427748/how-do-i-turn-on-rtti-with-cygwin) was tagged `[c++] [cocos2d-iphone] [cygwin] [ndk] [rtti]` and did not mention "android" anywhere, nor did its answer.  This question should therefore have shown up in the search results, right?

[ndk](/questions/tagged/ndk) isn't a special Android tag with the little green icon, unlike [android-ndk](/questions/tagged/android-ndk), so this behavior is unexpected to me.  Is it because [ndk](/questions/tagged/ndk) mentions Android in its wiki?

Related: [Merge [ndk] into [android-ndk] and blacklist the former one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113518/merge-ndk-into-android-ndk/)

Comment: It's because search thinks you want posts tagged [tag:ndk], not tagged [tag:android] or [tag:android-ndk], and with the literal text "-android", although it's probably ignoring the hyphen and looking for "android" directly, which, as you've mentioned, that post doesn't contain. Hmm, does the `-` operator even work for non-tags?

Comment: @TimStone Hmm, thanks for the tip.  `-"android"` doesn't seem to help.  `-` [appears to be undocumented](http://stackoverflow.com/search) in the first place, so I suppose I should be grateful it even works for tags :P

Comment: I think it does work with text, just perhaps not if tags are also present? (In which case it seems to be looking for the literal text "-term")

Comment: @TimStone Well that is just unhelpful.  Hopefully someone from SE clarifies.

Answer (score 4):

"The minus operator can only be used with tags" isn't accurate, the `-` operator works on text terms as well, it's just not working *in this case*.

The reason you're getting no results here is you can't search for **only** the absence of a word. If you were something for *something* and not *nothing*, then you'd get a result, for example:

- [[c#] [java] [testing]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+java+testing) (7 results)
- [[c#] [java] [testing] unit](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%5Bjava%5D+%5Btesting%5D+unit) (6 results)
- [[c#] [java] [testing] unit -mocks](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%5Bjava%5D+%5Btesting%5D+unit+-mocks) (5 results)

We can look into supporting this, but it's not a trivial change due to how tags are worked in here (they're handled separately to some degree).  Lucene currently sees your search as *only* the absence of a term, not even recognizing that there is some restriction (the tags) in place narrowing the result set.  I'll see what we can do here.

Comment: Ahhh, of course. That makes much more sense, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: That's cool.  I'm fine with how it works (though thanks for looking into it, that would be even better), but can we get that spelled out on the search page?