# Update search tips to include use of minus operator

Tags: feature-request, search, tips

The [search tips](https://stackoverflow.com/search) make no mention of the minus operator and its ability to eliminate search results that contain certain words.

Note that this is **not** a duplicate of [Update the search tips page to describe the use of the minus operator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113542/182807), which is concerned with the use of the minus operator with tags. (Yes, the question mentions documenting the minus operator with search terms, but those involved in the dialog became sidetracked discussing the feasibility of using the operator with tags.)

Also, I was not sure as to whether I should tag this as "advanced-search" or simply "search."

Comment: Whenever a while back was http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19253/exclude-specific-words-in-stackoverflow-search/19259#comment401274_19259

Comment: @random Yeah, I was slapping myself for having missed that (that is, the inclusion of that functionality) yesterday, in that very comment thread. Then today, I went to read the tips once again and realized that my ignorance was not without reason.